# dc.js wrong time format

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm new with dc.js.

On the x-axis I get pm/am time value and I whant the 24 hour time value.
What is wrong in my code?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
    { "quarter": "Q1", "hits": 10410, "date": "16:00" },
    { "quarter": "Q1", "hits": 10601, "date": "16:15" },
    { "quarter": "Q1", "hits": 10851, "date": "16:30" },

var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%H:%M');

    hitslineChart
    .width(500).height(200)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(hits_2011,"2011")
    .renderArea(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([timeFormat.parse('15:00'), timeFormat.parse('20:00')]))
    .elasticX(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the axis' `tickFormat` separately like this:

```
hitslineChart.xAxis().tickFormat(timeFormat);
```

See working JFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/q1rbq6a2/1/

Documentation: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#xaxisxaxis